# Google App Script copy folders and files based on form response value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just ran into some trouble. Thank you in advance for any help. I just updated a script with a if statement that I needed to add for a response in a new form. My goal is to copy a folder and the sub folders and files of two different of "source" folders based on a value from a form response. So for instance if the response is 'Production' then copy the "TestTempFolder" if the response is 'Creative' then copy the "TestTempFolder2" to the new folder that has been created and moved to a "Projects" folder that stores all the projects. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my updated script:

```
function start() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//Returns the currently active spreadsheet, or null if there is none.
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();//Gets the active sheet in a spreadsheet.
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();//Returns the position of the last row that has content.
var projectTypeRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow,2);
var projectType = projectTypeRange.getValues();

if (projectType == 'Production'){
productionCopy();
}
else if (projectType == 'Creative'){
creativeCopy();
}


function productionCopy(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//Returns the currently active spreadsheet, or null if there is none.
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();//Gets the active sheet in a spreadsheet.
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();//Returns the position of the last row that has content.
var projectNameRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 3);//Returns the range with the top left cell at the given coordinates.
var projectName = projectNameRange.getValues();//Returns the value of the top-left cell in the range. 
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
var startcell = sh.getRange('E2').getValue();
var colValues = sh.getRange('E2:E').getValues();// get all the values in column A in an array
var max=0;// define the max variable to a minimal value
for(var r in colValues){ // iterate the array
  var vv=colValues[r][0].toString().replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');// remove the letters from the string to convert to number
if(Number(vv)>max){max=vv};// get the highest numeric value in th column, no matter what happens in the column... this runs at array level so it is very fast
}
max++ ; // increment to be 1 above max value
sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(), 5).setValue(Utilities.formatString('CG%06d',max));// and write it back to sheet's last row.
var projectIdRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 5);
var projectId = projectIdRange.getValues();//Returns the value of the top-left cell in the range. 

var clientNameRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow,3);
var clientName = clientNameRange.getValues();
var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyy")
var productionSourceFolder = "TestTempFolder";
var targetFolder = "target";
var source = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(productionSourceFolder);
var target = DriveApp.createFolder(projectId + "_" + projectName + "_" + clientName + "_" + curDate);

if (source.hasNext()) {
copyFolder(source.next(), target);
}

DriveApp.getFolderById('0BwrizIzPM38bUGFPV2E1Q0JSMms').addFolder(target);
DriveApp.removeFolder(target);

function copyFolder(source, target) {
var folders = source.getFolders();
var files   = source.getFiles();

while(files.hasNext()) {
var file = files.next();
file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);
}

while(folders.hasNext()) {
var subFolder = folders.next();
var folderName = subFolder.getName();
var targetFolder = target.createFolder(folderName);
copyFolder(subFolder, targetFolder);
}  

}

function creativeCopy(){

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//Returns the currently active spreadsheet, or null if there is none.
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();//Gets the active sheet in a spreadsheet.
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();//Returns the position of the last row that has content.
var projectNameRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 3);//Returns the range with the top left cell at the given coordinates.
var projectName = projectNameRange.getValues();//Returns the value of the top-left cell in the range. 
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
var startcell = sh.getRange('E2').getValue();
var colValues = sh.getRange('E2:E').getValues();// get all the values in column A in an array
var max=0;// define the max variable to a minimal value
for(var r in colValues){ // iterate the array
  var vv=colValues[r][0].toString().replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');// remove the letters from the string to convert to number
if(Number(vv)>max){max=vv};// get the highest numeric value in th column, no matter what happens in the column... this runs at array level so it is very fast
}
max++ ; // increment to be 1 above max value
sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(), 5).setValue(Utilities.formatString('CG%06d',max));// and write it back to sheet's last row.
var projectIdRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 5);
var projectId = projectIdRange.getValues();//Returns the value of the top-left cell in the range.  
var clientNameRange = clientNameRange.getRange(lastRow,3);
var clientName = clientNameRange.getValues();
var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyy")
var creativeSourceFolder = "TestTempFolder2";
var targetFolder = "target";
var source = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(creativeSourceFolder);
var target = DriveApp.createFolder(projectId + "_" + projectName + "_" + clientName + "_" + curDate);

if (source.hasNext()) {
copyFolder(source.next(), target);
}

DriveApp.getFolderById('0BwrizIzPM38bUGFPV2E1Q0JSMms').addFolder(target);
DriveApp.removeFolder(target);

var folders = source.getFolders();
var files   = source.getFiles();

while(files.hasNext()) {
var file = files.next();
file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);
}

while(folders.hasNext()) {
var subFolder = folders.next();
var folderName = subFolder.getName();
var targetFolder = target.createFolder(folderName);
copyFolder(subFolder, targetFolder);
}  
} 
}
}
```

I now get this error: ReferenceError: "creativeCopy" is not defined. (line 13, file "Code"). I am not sure what I am doing wrong any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some mismatch of brackets.

Try this.

```
function start() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Returns the currently active spreadsheet, or null if there is none.
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); //Gets the active sheet in a spreadsheet.
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); //Returns the position of the last row that has content.
    var projectTypeRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2);
    var projectType = projectTypeRange.getValues();

    if (projectType == 'Production') {
        productionCopy();
    } else if (projectType == 'Creative') {
        creativeCopy();
    }
}

function productionCopy() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Returns the currently active spreadsheet, or null if there is none.
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); //Gets the active sheet in a spreadsheet.
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); //Returns the position of the last row that has content.
    var projectNameRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 3); //Returns the range with the top left cell at the given coordinates.
    var projectName = projectNameRange.getValues(); //Returns the value of the top-left cell in the range. 
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    var startcell = sh.getRange('E2').getValue();
    var colValues = sh.getRange('E2:E').getValues(); // get all the values in column A in an array
    var max = 0; // define the max variable to a minimal value
    for (var r in colValues) { // iterate the array
        var vv = colValues[r][0].toString().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); // remove the letters from the string to convert to number
        if (Number(vv) > max) {
            max = vv
        }; // get the highest numeric value in th column, no matter what happens in the column... this runs at array level so it is very fast
    }
    max++; // increment to be 1 above max value
    sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(), 5).setValue(Utilities.formatString('CG%06d', max)); // and write it back to sheet's last row.
    var projectIdRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 5);
    var projectId = projectIdRange.getValues(); //Returns the value of the top-left cell in the range. 

    var clientNameRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 3);
    var clientName = clientNameRange.getValues();
    var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyy")
    var productionSourceFolder = "TestTempFolder";
    var targetFolder = "target";
    var source = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(productionSourceFolder);
    var target = DriveApp.createFolder(projectId + "_" + projectName + "_" + clientName + "_" + curDate);

    if (source.hasNext()) {
        copyFolder(source.next(), target);
    }

    DriveApp.getFolderById('0BwrizIzPM38bUGFPV2E1Q0JSMms').addFolder(target);
    DriveApp.removeFolder(target);
}

function copyFolder(source, target) {
    var folders = source.getFolders();
    var files = source.getFiles();

    while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);
    }

    while (folders.hasNext()) {
        var subFolder = folders.next();
        var folderName = subFolder.getName();
        var targetFolder = target.createFolder(folderName);
        copyFolder(subFolder, targetFolder);
    }

}

function creativeCopy() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Returns the currently active spreadsheet, or null if there is none.
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); //Gets the active sheet in a spreadsheet.
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); //Returns the position of the last row that has content.
    var projectNameRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 3); //Returns the range with the top left cell at the given coordinates.
    var projectName = projectNameRange.getValues(); //Returns the value of the top-left cell in the range. 
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    var startcell = sh.getRange('E2').getValue();
    var colValues = sh.getRange('E2:E').getValues(); // get all the values in column A in an array
    var max = 0; // define the max variable to a minimal value
    for (var r in colValues) { // iterate the array
        var vv = colValues[r][0].toString().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); // remove the letters from the string to convert to number
        if (Number(vv) > max) {
            max = vv
        }; // get the highest numeric value in th column, no matter what happens in the column... this runs at array level so it is very fast
    }
    max++; // increment to be 1 above max value
    sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(), 5).setValue(Utilities.formatString('CG%06d', max)); // and write it back to sheet's last row.
    var projectIdRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 5);
    var projectId = projectIdRange.getValues(); //Returns the value of the top-left cell in the range.  
    var clientNameRange = clientNameRange.getRange(lastRow, 3);
    var clientName = clientNameRange.getValues();
    var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyy")
    var creativeSourceFolder = "TestTempFolder2";
    var targetFolder = "target";
    var source = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(creativeSourceFolder);
    var target = DriveApp.createFolder(projectId + "_" + projectName + "_" + clientName + "_" + curDate);

    if (source.hasNext()) {
        copyFolder(source.next(), target);
    }

    DriveApp.getFolderById('0BwrizIzPM38bUGFPV2E1Q0JSMms').addFolder(target);
    DriveApp.removeFolder(target);

    var folders = source.getFolders();
    var files = source.getFiles();

    while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);
    }

    while (folders.hasNext()) {
        var subFolder = folders.next();
        var folderName = subFolder.getName();
        var targetFolder = target.createFolder(folderName);
        copyFolder(subFolder, targetFolder);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it. I just removed: `function copyFolder(source, target) {` somehow. I just added it and it works. Thank you again Adelin.